# i want to change registry key but it back to default value after restart

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_04D9&PID_AD50&MI_00\7&1423bb6d&0&0000

key is " Capabilities "

so i want to change the value but after restart comeback to the default value

is it possible to do that?

Comment: In order to properly answer this question we must know the reason you are modifying the key in question

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to change a registry key related to a USB hardware device.

The nature of USB devices is that they are uninstalled on a remove and installed on a plug-in action. As a result their settings are removed as well, and only if the usb device comes with additional drivers that you must install too, then the registry keys for that software remain.

As such, it is not possible to prevent this from happening because the uninstall is being performed on such high level that if you deny access, it is very likely, the device itself will stop working too.

The best thing you can do is create a registry export of that value to a .reg file and execute it every time the device is plugged into your computer.

That said, this seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You are likely trying to solve another problem by performing this action, where the actual problem has a different (and better) alternative solution that you should be trying instead.

If this is indeed the case, I suggest to post a new question and ask what you ultimately want to accomplish. Given that editing your question invalidate this answer, you should not edit your question.

If you don't plugin and out the device, but keep it in between reboots (yes, the device gets installed/uninstalled then too, consider putting the .reg key in your system startup) Note that it may not work if the regkey is executed before the device is installed.